# Docker Compose Up - Ошибка при запуске

Tags: python, docker, django-rest-framework

запуская `docker-compose up` я получаю ошибку:

```
school-co-server-1  | Performing system checks...
school-co-server-1  |
school-co-server-1  | Exception in thread django-main-thread:
school-co-server-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 66, in __getitem__
school-co-server-1  |     return self._engines[alias]
school-co-server-1  | KeyError: 'django'
school-co-server-1  |
school-co-server-1  | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
school-co-server-1  |
school-co-server-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 121, in get_package_libraries
school-co-server-1  |     module = import_module(entry[1])
school-co-server-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
school-co-server-1  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
school-co-server-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
school-co-server-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
school-co-server-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
school-co-server-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
school-co-server-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
school-co-server-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 66, in __getitem__
school-co-server-1  |     return self._engines[alias]
school-co-server-1  | KeyError: 'django'
school-co-server-1  |
school-co-server-1  | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
school-co-server-1  |
school-co-server-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 121, in get_package_libraries
school-co-server-1  |     module = import_module(entry[1])  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
school-co-server-1  |
school-co-server-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
school-co-server-1  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
school-co-server-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/templatetags/rest_framework.py", line 12, in <module>
school-co-server-1  |     from rest_framework.renderers import HTMLFormRenderer
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 22, in <module>
school-co-server-1  |     from rest_framework import VERSION, exceptions, serializers, status
school-co-server-1  | ImportError: cannot import name 'serializers' from 'rest_framework' (/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/__init__.py)
school-co-server-1  |
school-co-server-1  | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
school-co-server-1  |
school-co-server-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
school-co-server-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
school-co-server-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
school-co-server-1  |     self.run()
school-co-server-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 910, in run
school-co-server-1  |     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
school-co-server-1  |     fn(*args, **kwargs)
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 124, in inner_run
school-co-server-1  |     self.check(display_num_errors=True)
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 438, in check
school-co-server-1  |     all_issues = checks.run_checks(
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 77, in run_checks
school-co-server-1  |       File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
school-co-server-1  | new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/checks.py", line 78, in check_dependencies
school-co-server-1  |     for engine in engines.all():
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in all
school-co-server-1  |     return [self[alias] for alias in self]
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in <listcomp>
school-co-server-1  |     return [self[alias] for alias in self]
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 81, in __getitem__
school-co-server-1  |     engine = engine_cls(params)
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 25, in __init__
school-co-server-1  |     options['libraries'] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
school-co-server-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 43, in get_templatetag_libraries
school-co-server-1  |     libraries = get_installed_libraries()
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 108, in get_installed_libraries
school-co-server-1  |     for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 123, in get_package_libraries
school-co-server-1  |     raise InvalidTemplateLibrary(
school-co-server-1  | django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'rest_framework.templatetags.
rest_framework': cannot import name 'serializers' from 'rest_framework' (/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/__init__.py)
school-co-server-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
school-co-server-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/templatetags/rest_framework.py", line 12, in <module>
school-co-server-1  |     from rest_framework.renderers import HTMLFormRenderer
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 22, in <module>
school-co-server-1  |     from rest_framework import VERSION, exceptions, serializers, status
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 29, in <module>
school-co-server-1  |     from rest_framework.fields import get_error_detail, set_value
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 32, in <module>
school-co-server-1  |     from pytz.exceptions import InvalidTimeError
school-co-server-1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytz'
school-co-server-1  |
school-co-server-1  | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
school-co-server-1  |
school-co-server-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/server/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
school-co-server-1  |     main()
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/server/manage.py", line 18, in main
school-co-server-1  |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 425, in execute_from_command_line
school-co-server-1  |     utility.execute()
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute
school-co-server-1  |     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 373, in run_from_argv
school-co-server-1  |     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 66, in execute
school-co-server-1  |     super().execute(*args, **options)
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 417, in execute
school-co-server-1  |     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 101, in handle
school-co-server-1  |     self.run(**options)
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 108, in run
school-co-server-1  |     autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 644, in run_with_reloader
school-co-server-1  |     start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 629, in start_django
school-co-server-1  |     reloader.run(django_main_thread)
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 334, in run
school-co-server-1  |     autoreload_started.send(sender=self)
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 170, in send
school-co-server-1  |     return [
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 171, in <listcomp>
school-co-server-1  |     (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/autoreload.py", line 44, in watch_for_template_changes
school-co-server-1  |     for directory in get_template_directories():
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/autoreload.py", line 17, in get_template_directories
school-co-server-1  |     for backend in engines.all():
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in all
school-co-server-1  |     return [self[alias] for alias in self]
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in <listcomp>
school-co-server-1  |     return [self[alias] for alias in self]
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 81, in __getitem__
school-co-server-1  |     engine = engine_cls(params)
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 25, in __init__
school-co-server-1  |     options['libraries'] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 43, in get_templatetag_libraries
school-co-server-1  |     libraries = get_installed_libraries()
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 108, in get_installed_libraries
school-co-server-1  |     for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
school-co-server-1  |   File "/home/web/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 123, in get_package_libraries
school-co-server-1  |     raise InvalidTemplateLibrary(
school-co-server-1  | django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'rest_framework.templatetags.
rest_framework': No module named 'pytz'
school-co-server-1 exited with code 1
```

Подскажите, с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: `No module named 'pytz'` возможно, вам нужно установить зависимости из requirements.txt, или так `pip install pytz`. В любом случае править Dockerfile. покажите Dockerfile и dockerfile-compose.yaml

Comment: @SeniorPomidor pip install pytz не работает :( тоже сначала попробовал, команда выполняется, но видимо не для того питона, может надо устанавливать для питона WSL, но я не могу найти как это сделать

Comment: Вам уже написали, нужен Dockerfile и docker-compose.yaml. Вы что-то делаете не правильно, но без этих файлов, сказать, что именно, нельзя. В текущем виде вопрос подлежит закрытию.